# How can i modify FontSize and FontFamily of the title inside a ShellContent element in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I have a ShellFlyoutMenu in my MAUI App which needs some modifications. I need to change the default FontSize and FontFamily

```
<ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Home}" Route="Home"/>
```

But i cant find a way to do this. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell includes three style classes, which are automatically applied to `FlyoutItem` and `MenuItem` objects. The style class names are `FlyoutItemLabelStyle`, `FlyoutItemImageStyle`, and `FlyoutItemLayoutStyle`.

If you want to change the `FontSize` and `FontFamily` of the FlayoutItem, you can add a style in `AppShell.xaml`

```
<Shell.Resources>   
    <!--  other code  -->
    <!--  add style here  -->
   <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label"> 
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="testFont" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"   Value="Header" />
    </Style>

</Shell.Resources>
```

Please remember add your font into folder `Resources/Fonts` and set `BuildAction` to `MauiFont`.

And configure your Font as follows:

```
public static class MauiProgram 
{
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                     // configure your font here
                     fonts.AddFont("Lobster-Regular.ttf", "testFont");
            });

            return builder.Build();
      }
}
```

**Note:**

For more information, you can check document : [Style FlyoutItem and MenuItem objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#style-flyoutitem-and-menuitem-objects).

Answer (score -1):

To change the default FontSize and FontFamily for the ShellContent in your ShellFlyoutMenu, you can modify the Style of the ShellContent inside the Shell.Resources section of your Shell page. Here's an example:

```
<Shell ...>
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ShellContent">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Home" />
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:Home />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Route" Value="Home" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Montserrat" />
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>

<!-- Your Shell Flyout Items and Content -->
```

In this example, the FontSize is set to 18 and the FontFamily is set to "Montserrat" for all instances of ShellContent within the Shell.
Make sure to replace "Home" with the appropriate values for your content. You can add additional Setter properties to customize other aspects of the ShellContent as needed.

Comment: This doesnt work, because the ShellContent tag doesn't have a FontSize or FontFamily property